# Laravel returns empty result with a date parameter of 0

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I write a MySQL query and have a where clause like such.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE date_field > 0
```

It works just fine.

However when I try and translate that in to my Laravel

```
$query = $this->getQB();
$query->where('date_field', '>', 0);
$return = $query->get($cols);
```

I get an empty result set.  I figured out I can change my where clause to say

```
$query->where('date_field', '!=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

and everything runs fine.

My question is: Why can't I do the greater than zero on a date field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think (but I am not sure) that it is because Laravel converts `0` to a string `'0'`. Try this:

```
$query->where(DB::raw('date_field > 0'));
```

**Edit**: This might work too (not checked):

```
$query->where('date_field', '>', DB::raw('0'));
```

**Edit 2**: I looked it up, and I think I am right about the string conversion, see: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L280

Here [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) is executed, and in the PHP documentation it says:

> All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR.